# Merging two different pyspark dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two pyspark dataframes with different values that I want to merge on some condition. The below is what I have

```
DF-1
date           person_surname     person_order_number      item                        
2017-08-09       pearson                  1                shoes
2017-08-09       zayne                    3                clothes

DF-2
date           person_surname      person_order_number    person_slary 
2017-08-09       pearson                  2                $1000
2017-08-09       zayne                    5                $2000
```

I want to merge DF1 and DF2 such that the surnames of the people match and the person_order_number is merged correct. So i want the following returned

```
 DF_pearson
 date       person_surname     person_order_number   item     salary                      
 2017-08-09    pearson                  1            shoes
 2017-08-09    pearson                  2                     $1000


  DF_Zayne
  date       person_surname     person_order_number   item    salary
  2017-08-09       zayne                    3        clothes
  2017-08-09       zayne                    5                $2000
```

How do i achieve this? I want to then perform operations on each of these dataframes as well.

Comment: union them and then filter with surnames into dataframes

Comment: unfortunately my main dataframes has many columns that it doesnt share with each other hence cannot do this.